# Right way to build dll

Tags: c++, dll, architecture

We have a class A (decleared below).

```
#ifdef DLL_ON_WORK
    #define DLL_SPEC __declspec(dllexport)
#else
    #define DLL_SEPC __declspec(dllimport)

class A
{
    friend B;
private:
    int a;
    int b;
    vector<int> c;

public:
    DLL_SPEC int Geta();
    DLL_SPEC int Getb();
    DLL_SPEC vector<int> Getc();
             int Calc();

private:
    void Seta(int val);
    void Setb(int val);
    void Setc(vector<int>& val);
};
```

**I have several questions.**

1. If class A will be dynamically and statically created and deleted in client code, must I mark whole class A as DLL_SPEC?
2. Need I create "special" version of header file for client code, something like SDK, in which will be deleted all private and unusable by client code methods and fields? Can I do that?
3. What actualy header file should provide if it will used in client code, full class declaration, or I can only specify class interface that should be used by client?

I know, that questions cross with each other, but I have some gaps in knowledge of building libraries and their further use in client code, and if you can recommend some  books or articles on this topic, it will be good.

Comment: You already jumped the shark by exposing std::vector.  Which exposes C++ implementation details (object layout, storage, exceptions) that requires the client programmer to use the exact same compiler, using the exact same build options, using the exact same CRT and C++ library.  So it doesn't matter anymore.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use the Factory-Pattern in your case (honestly, I always use the factory pattern).

In that case, you will only export two functions

```
DLL_SPEC A *createClassA();
DLL_SPEC void destroyClassA(A *obj);
```

for the rest, you need any specifier `virtual`, this makes thinks much easier to handle.

The advantage:

- You can split your header files into two (the factory und the usual definition). Where the definition of your class is identical for both, user and dll.
- No macro-modifier in front of every method.

The disadvantage:

- You can only create and destroy objects via the factory functions. DLL Memory bounderies will prevent using new in dll and delete in your main code. But that's not really a problem. If you use `std::shared_ptr` you are able to provide a special destruction function.

You can also put your factory functions inside your class as `static` methods. In that case you can declare constructor and destructor private, which prevents user of your dll to create A without the factory:

```
#ifdef DLL_ON_WORK
    #define DLL_SPEC __declspec(dllexport)
#else
    #define DLL_SEPC __declspec(dllimport)

class A
{
    friend B;
private:
    int a;
    int b;
    vector<int> c;

public:
    virtual int Geta();
    virtual int Getb();
    virtual vector<int> Getc();
    virtual int Calc();
    static DLL_SPEC A *createClassA();
    static DLL_SPEC void destroyClassA(A *obj);
private:
    virtual void Seta(int val);
    virtual void Setb(int val);
    virtual void Setc(vector<int>& val);
};
```

Last but not least. Work with interface-pattern. Only export the interface, but not the class itself. Name your class from 'A' to 'Aimplementation' which is inherited from an interface 'IA' which will be exported. The interface will be like that in your case:

```
#ifdef DLL_ON_WORK
    #define DLL_SPEC __declspec(dllexport)
#else
    #define DLL_SEPC __declspec(dllimport)

class IA
{
public:
    virtual int Geta()=0; // with C++11 please use =nullptr instead of
    virtual int Getb()=0; 
    virtual vector<int> Getc()=0;
    virtual int Calc();


    static DLL_SPEC IA *createA();
    static DLL_SPEC void destroyA(IA *obj);
};
```

which is, IMHO the slickest way and also an answer for your three questions.

**UPDATE**

I was forgetting the `virtual` keyword before, which is necessary for this solution. The keyword virtual forces the compiler to generate a **vtable** with entry-points to the methods with every object created with `new`.

A typical implementation of the factory methods in the DLL looks like follow:

```
IA* IA::createA()
{
 return new Aimplemetation;
}

void IA::destroyA(IA *obj)
{
  delete static_cast<Aimplementation *>(obj);
}
```

To invoke `Geta` in the code of an user of the DLL, the main would look like:

```
void main()
{
 IA *a=IA::createIA();
 a->Geta();
 IA::destroyIA(a);
}
```

@Christophe summed it up like followed in the comment section:

> So the trick is that on the client side, the compiler deduces from the
>   header's class definition the vtable layout of the object. He then
>   generates the call using the vtable indirection without need to expose
>   the function name ! and of course using the same calling conventions.

Usually I only export two functions per library. A create/init and destroy/close. With the first instance of a class given back I expose more or less the whole interface. This makes also the code more readable in my opinion. This kind of pattern can be also used for plugin-systems where a client (for e.g. Chrome) provides the header and the plugin-DLL has to fulfill the interfaces.

Comment: Interesting. But i didn't unerstand how the client could invoque Geta() on the object received from the factory ?

Comment: @Christophe I had a little flaw in my sample. The update will show correct how it works

Comment: ok, I see.  So the trick is that on the client side, the compiler deduces from the header's class definition the vtable layout of the object.  He then generates the call using the vtable indirection without need to expose the function name ! and of course using the same calling conventions.  Excellent !

Comment: @Christophe your sumup hit the point exactly, I included it into the answer